# XSS-Attack: Is it possible to execute JS when input value is set?

Tags: javascript, xss

I currently tested my app against XSS and wondered if the following example could be exploited.

Here is what I do: I get an unescaped response from the server and set it directly to an input's value.

I know I should escape on the server but am curious if this could be exploited.

I already came this far to produce a syntax error, but was not able to execute the script...

```js
document.getElementById('test').value = '"/><script>alert(1);</script>';
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text"/>
```

Can you change this example though that the `alert(1);` actually executes?

Thanks for your help. I'm really curious :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning anything to value of an input will not make it execute. Only assignments to event handlers like onerror, onmouseover, onfocus etc. will make it execute.

I'm guessing the syntax error is because `</script>` breaks your script tag, and thus you are left with invalid javascript. Quite similar to what i describe here: http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=91

Comment: Thanks. So regardless of what obscure or obfuscated String I will insert, it will never execute? There is really absolutely no way to bypass this?

Comment: Setting the value attribute should be a safe operation regardless of content. If you find anything, that would mean you found a browser bug, not a bug in the application.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help.